# How to get a string using Jquery and JSON when it starts with an array?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

So I have this here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0jto.png

I need to get the wins for the the 2nd of the array playerStatSummaries
My current code:

```
unrankedWins = json[playerStatSummaries[1]].wins;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use JSON.parse to convert response into an object and then access the appropriate property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this,

I am not sure your `var json` is a string or object!

If `json` is a sting, parse the string,

```
var parsedjson = $.parseJSON(json);
alert(parsedjson.playStatSummaries[1].wins);
```

`json` is not a string,

```
 alert(json.playerStatSummaries[1].wins);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had earlier code prior and forgot to mention. I would've posted it but I cant really indent in the textbox for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment to your question, `parse` is the way to go here.

```
var parsed = $.parseJSON(json);
var unrankedWins = parsed.playStatSummaries[1].wins;
```

[Fiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/aL9nwp6m/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

**

```
Variable : @result : your json object

    for (var key in result) {
       for (var j = 0; j < result[key].length; j++) {
         unrankedWins = result[key][j].wins;
    }
    }
```

**

you can parse all the values in the key playerStatSummaries , if in future you have multiple keys, now you have single key playerStatSummaries, but I think it will work.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
  var JsonData={......};

  var newObj=JSON.parse(JsonData);


  var unrankedWins =playerStatSummaries[1].wins;
 consloe.log(unrankedWins );
```